# как правильно устранить "запах" кода "Большой класс"?

Tags: ооп, рефакторинг

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с "запахом кода", который называется Большой класс. У меня есть класс, в котором создается GUI. На GUI добавляется панель, на которую добавляется много элементов управления. В общем, все это имеет достаточно сложную структуру.
Вот метод, с которого начинается создание этой панели:

```
private static JPanel createTasksMainInfoPanel(JTabbedPane taskTabbedPane) {
    JPanel panelForMainInfo = new JPanel();
    //code...
    addComponentForMainInfoBox(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo, new String(),
            createTypeChoicePanel(max, min));
    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    createListenerForOk(ok, fieldForName, fieldForVarQuantity,
            FieldForLimitQuantity, FieldForCritQuantity, max,
            taskTabbedPane);
    addComponentForMainInfoBox(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo, new String(), ok);
    panelForMainInfo.add(verticalBoxForTaskMainInfo);
    return panelForMainInfo;
}
```

Здесь я привел только начало и конец метода. В середине еще строк 50. Плюс в конце у меня идут вызовы других методов, которые так же нужны что бы создать эту панель. В них приходится передавать кучу параметров. В общем, в результате я имею длинные методы с большим списком параметров. И мой класс, где создается GUI разрастается до огромных размеров. Не лучше ли мне выделить для создания этой панели отдельный класс? Тогда все что я передавал в параметрах можно было бы сделать полями этого класса. И можно было бы выделить более компактные методы и без огромных списков параметров. Или может я вообще зря это затеял. Ведь добавится еще один класс, а значит новые связи между классами. К тому же, не противоречит ли это принципу единственной обязанности(single responsibility principle)? Ведь эта панель входит в GUI, то есть ее отрисовка входит в обязанность этого класса GUI?

Comment: Простите мою неграмотность, это Java? У вас есть возможность создать UI через WYSIWYG редактор? А потом подключить UI к вашему классу.

Answer (score 6):

Под "большим классом" Фаулер понимает не размер в строках, а размер функциональности. То есть когда в классе много разнородных ответственностей класс считается "большим". Следовательно, чтобы назвать класс "большим" надо составить перечень его ответственностей и определить насколько они разнородные.

В вашем случае функция класса состоит в сопоставлении визуальной структуры графического интерфейса и внутренней структуры графического интерфейса. Поэтому на нем лежит две ответственности: знать визуальную структуру и знать внутреннюю структуру.

Визуальная структура графического интерфейса это то, что мы видим на экране: кнопка внутри панельки, панелька на форме, форма слева на окне, нажатие на кнопку выводит диалог, и так далее. Тут все понятно.

Внутренняя структура графического интерфейса это то, как связаны объекты контролов между собой: кто кого содержит, кто кому сообщения посылает, как контролы создаются и настраиваются, и прочее. Но к внутренней структуре графического интерфейса не относится то, как объекты контролов связаны с другими объектами неконтролами! Это другая ответственность.

Судя по коду, который вы привели, у вас ничего такого не наблюдается, поэтому ваш класс нельзя назвать "большим". Если вас смущает его размер в строках, посмотрите на это с другой стороны. Сейчас у вас одно место где весь графический интерфейс создается и настраивается, то есть когда вы хотите что-то поменять на форме вам не надо вспоминать в какой файл смотреть - это один и тот же файл. Если вы разнесете эту логику по 10 классам, то у вас будет 10 мест для поиска.